# Small mini-itx case with support for PCIe 4.0 GPUs

Tags: desktop, pcie, case, mini-pc

I want to build a small factor mini-itx PC for gaming around a motherboard based on AMD X570. Ideally, I am looking for cases <20lt in volume. Slightly bigger cases (<24lt) would also do.

The problem is that with these volume limitations, any good looking cases I've found (e.g. [NZXT H1](https://www.nzxt.com/products/h1-matte-black) or [Phanteks Evolv Shift 2](http://www.phanteks.com/Evolv-Shift2.html)) use PCIe risers that are only PCIe 3.0 compatible. I've also found some small factor cases that support PCIe 4.0 GPUs that are yet to go on sale (e.g. [Thor-Zone Mjolnir](https://thor-zone.com/mini-itx/)).

So, I am looking for recommendations for mini-itx cases with:

- streamlined look (see examples above),
- volume <20lt (or at worst <24lt),
- PCIe 4.0 GPU compatibility (either via a compatible riser or by allowing directly attaching the GPU to the motherboard),
- availability within Q1 2021 (or at worst Q2 2021).

Speculations on whether/when one of the models mentioned above will be updated to PCIe 4.0 are also welcome in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

[SSUPD Meshlicious](https://ssupd.com/products/meshlicious) should fit your needs.

The riser they use, by LINKUP, is also available alone so you can order one of those. But you need to check case compatibility.

A comment on H1: it's been recalled for being a fire hazard (GamersNexus covered it on YouTube).

Comment: @m000 it just entered the market in US, might be we'll get it with a delay.

Comment: Meshlicious looks great, and even has room for 3.5" drives it seems. Can't find an EU retailer though.
For H1, the problem causing the fire hazard is well understood and the available fix (nylon screw) seems perfectly adequate. NZXT still has my respect for taking ownership of their design error and doing the recall. Hoping they release an H1 redesign soon, and that it will be PCIe 4.0 compatible.

Comment: @m000 two things on H1: they tried to cover it up, first reports of the issue were out there in December. Second: when you replace the parts in the H1 in several years will you remember about the screw? That's all I'm going to say

Comment: Any evidence about a cover-up? Of course they'd want to investigate the extent of the problem before going for a full recall. No sane company would blindly believe a YT channel without making their own assessment. And of course I would remember about the screw. But I would also put a sticker next to it too as an extra reminder.

Comment: @m000 they did delete posts on their subreddit, mostly though the response was delayed. Personally I think that the screw wasn't an adequate response, few people are as meticulous as you.